# Функция fopen_s() можно ли как-то обойтись без второго аргумента filename?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Функция fopen_s() можно ли как-то обойтись без второго аргумента filename если он мне не нужен в этой функции чтобы открыть безымяный текстовый файл ?

Comment: Что значит не нужен? А что вы собрались открывать? Это обязательный параметр

Comment: может человек хочет открыть безымяный файл. Что бы все работало, а файла не было (и такое почти возможно - просто файл нужно удалить после открытия).

Comment: А что, по-вашему, есть «безымянный файл»? Вопрос серьёзный.

Comment: безымяный файл - файл без имени. И такое может понадобиться. Варианты реализации - открывается файл в temp каталоге, и тут же удаляется. В результате дескриптор есть, в него можно читать-писать, а по закрытию приложения - самоудаляется. В файловой системе он видимый на доли секунды.

Второй способ - сделать симуляцию и создавать файл в ОЗУ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C нет ни перегруженных функций, ни аргументов по умолчанию.

Согласно стандарту C (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 2 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   includes a prototype, **the number of arguments shall agree with the
>   number of parameters**.

и

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype,...If the number of arguments does not
>   equal the number of parameters, **the behavior is undefined**.

Что касается имени файла, то (ствндврт C, 7.21.3 Files)

> 8 Functions that open additional (nontemporary) files **require a file
>   name**, which is a string. **The rules for composing valid file names
>   are implementation-defined**. Whether the same file can be
>   simultaneously open multiple times is also implementation-defined.

Например, я пытался создать файл с "пустым именем", используя онлайновый компилятор, то есть в виде `""`, то он не был создан.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *output;

    output = fopen( "", "w" );

    if ( output ) puts( "File was created" );
    else puts( "File was not created" );

    if ( output ) fclose( output );
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
File was not created
```

В этой программе вызов функции `fopen` можно заменить на вызов функции `fopen_s`.